# how to extract hashtags and display them groups by descending dates? (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hashtag

I created a new model called 'hashtags' and a new table in my database

Here's the schema.db

```
create_table "hashtags", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "hashtags"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end
```

hashtags.rb

```
class Hashtags < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hashtags, :post_id
end


def create
  hashtag_regex = /\b#\w\w+/
  @post = current_user.posts.build(params[:post])
  @post.hashtags = @post.text.scan(hashtag_regex)
end
```

Inside the post model, this is what I've added

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :hashtags, dependent: :destroy
```

For all posts where there's a hashtag (or could be 2+ hashtags), I want to list them in descending order by date in a new page called '/hashtags'.
So this is how I want it to show in view

```
4/30/2013
#tag3 #tag2 by user2
#tag1 by user5

4/29/2013
#tagz by user10
#tagx #tagy by user3

4/25/2013
#tagz #tagy #tagx by user2
```

Inside views\static_pages\hashtags.html.erb

I'm trying to create this view, but how could I best go about this?

Comment: Are the hashtags being saved correctly?

Comment: I just realized that they're not being saved

Comment: I added `hashtag_regex = /\b#\w\w+/` and 
  `@post.hashtags = @post.content.scan(hashtag_regex)`, into the post controller under create but I'm now getting `uninitialized constant Post::Hashtag`. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

To save the hash tags you need a before save callback method, and get rid of that logic in the controller.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

    after_save :process_hashtags

    def process_hashtags
       hashtag_regex = /\B#\w\w+/
       text_hashtags = text.scan(hashtag_regex)
       text_hashtags.each do |tag|
         hashtags.create name: tag
       end
     end
end
```

This callback will iterate through the array of hashtags that it finds in the text, and create a `Hashtag` model and associate it with the `Post` model.

Let me know if it works, as it might need some adjustments.

Comment: I made some slight adjustments to this  `def process_hashtags
       hashtag_regex = /\b#\w\w+/
       text_hashtags = content.scan(hashtag_regex)
       text_hashtags.each do |tag|
         hashtags.create hashtags: tag
       end
     end` but it still doesn't seem to be saving. I included the `before_save` as well

Comment: no, not getting any errors. I'm viewing if the save went through using the rails console. I'm running `u=Hashtags.all` but it looks nil

Comment: I just tested your regular expression and it wasn't working. Try using this `/\B#(\w+)/i`

Comment: the hashtag is not getting saved and gives this error `You cannot call create unless the parent is saved`. I tried using `has_many :hashtags, :autosave => true` to solve the issue but this didn't fix it

Comment: that makes sense! Let's save the post first, and then process the hashtags. Change the before_save to after_save

Comment: now, it brings back the original error that I posted above using the other option. I'm getting `uninitialized constant Post::Hashtag`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29213/discussion-between-alexbrand-and-amy-brown)

Comment: The table has to stay plural

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would dot it in your Model: For

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :hashtags, dependent: :destroy
 after_commit :process_hashtags

def process_hashtags
    hashtag_regex = (/#\w+/)       
    text_hashtags = content.to_s.scan(hashtag_regex)       
    text_hashtags.each do |name| 
        HashTag.create name: name, address: user.country       
    end      
    end
 end
```

Model for # for hashTags

```
class HashTag < ApplicationRecord
 
  belongs_to :post

end
```